# Get amount of customer per city and the total of customer per country One table

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I need these two SQL Scripts into one: to get amount of customer per city and the total of customer per country from AdventureWorks database

I almost have it done, the problem is that I need to make one single `TABLE`, having problems with Multiple `COUNT` 's.

```
 USE AdventureWorks2014
SELECT person.Address.City, Count (*) AS Total
FROM person.Address
INNER JOIN person.StateProvince
    ON person.Address.StateProvinceID = person.StateProvince.StateProvinceID
GROUP BY person.Address.City 
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

[First scrip Returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os4JK.png)

```
USE AdventureWorks2014

SELECT person.StateProvince.CountryRegionCode, Count (*) AS Total
FROM person.Address
INNER JOIN person.StateProvince
    ON person.Address.StateProvinceID = person.StateProvince.StateProvinceID
GROUP BY person.StateProvince.CountryRegionCode 
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

[Second script returns:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgHSr.png)

Comment: You should show the results that you want.

Comment: Let me edit it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is a `UNION ALL`.  However, you can do essentially the same thing with `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.City, sp.CountryRegionCode) as City_or_Region,
       Count(*) AS Total
FROM person.Address a INNER JOIN
     person.StateProvince sp
     ON a.StateProvinceID = sp.StateProvinceID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a.City), (sp.CountryRegionCode))
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

Note that this makes a couple of assumptions about the data:

- `City` is never `NULL`.
- `City` and `CountryRegionCode` never have the same values (you can split these into separate columns if needed).

Comment: I get error "Invalid column name 'CountryRegionCode'." , Maybe because CountryRegionCode is not a column of person.Addres